# What's the best way to handle limited membership periods and/or expiry?

Tags: members, zoo-visitor, expire

This doesn't seem to be part of EE core, which - honestly - surprises me.  Maybe I'm missing something.

I'd like to be able to limit membership periods by setting an expiry date on specific members (not the group), when approved by the admin in the CP.

I don't believe this is an unusual requirement, how have you all handled this in your installations?

The installation in question is version 2.5.2.

Thanks very much for viewing.

Comment: Are you using native members or Zoo Visitor? If Zoo Visitor you could add a custom date field that expires the member and have the site admin edit this when approving membership.

Comment: or just use the entry expiry date field on the entry that Zoo Visitor creates.

Comment: If you need those members in more than one location - I wouldn't use the entry expiry date as they will be expired. However if that is the only location needed then yes entry expiry would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I have implemented - as laid out by @CreateSean and @foamcow - is to use Zoo Visitor and EE's channel expiry field for each members' Zoo Visitor channel entry.

Zoo Visitor holds the entered expiration date for the logged in user's entry as a global variable...

> {visitor:global:expiration_date}

which I used in the conditional to automatically display (or not display) the limited content.

The user is still a member of the site, in the appropriate group.

Once on the right track, everything I needed was here - https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-visitor/viewthread/2823

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the Charge subscriptions addon - http://squarebit.co.uk/software/expressionengine/charge/ - that will allow members to register for specific periods and have them automatically "expire" after a certain time (though it changes the members' group on expiry, not removing them). If you allow it member can renew their subscription as well.

Comment: Thanks Bluedreamer. Members are not tied to any sort of payment or fee. It's simply access to resources available for a limited time.  It seems Charge is based on an action/transaction.